# bool doesn't go true in my method

Tags: c#, methods, boolean

I'm using some method to set some values, but sadly it doesn't set my value to `true`, even when I tell him to be `true`.
Below you can find the method with the actual values that I write:

```
LogPanelData(rcv_bStartGlue, send_bStartGlueACK, send_bStartGlueNACK, bLogRobotFile_OK, rcv_sFileNameRobot, LogLines);
```

Below you can find the full method with all the info in it. In a normal case `a_rcvValue` and `a_LogFile_OK`are both `true`. and the first time I load this the `a_sendValueACk = false` (in this case that would be `send_bStartGlueACK`).

As you can see in the method the second time I get in this method with the same line(as above) it should not go in the first if statement, since `a_sendValueACK` should be `true`. but it tells my `send_bStartGlueACK` is false all the time so that isn't correct. So how can I solve this that my `send_bStartGlueACK`will be true when I set it true in this method?

```
public void LogPanelData(bool a_rcvValue, bool a_sendValueACK, bool a_sendValueNACK, bool a_LogFile_OK, string a_LogFileName, string a_LogLines)
{
    if (a_rcvValue && !a_sendValueACK && a_LogFile_OK)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter Sw = new StreamWriter(a_LogFileName, true);
            //regel schrijven
            Sw.WriteLine(a_LogLines);

            //SW afsluiten!!
            Sw.Close();

            //lijst opvullen met de regels voor output in programma
            listOutput.Add(a_LogFileName);
            listOutput.Add(a_LogLines);

            a_sendValueACK = true; //<<< This does go true, but not the value I send with it
        }
        catch
        {
            a_LogFileName = "Kan gegevens niet opslaan!";
            a_sendValueNACK = true;
        }
    }
    if (a_rcvValue && !a_LogFile_OK)
    {
        a_sendValueNACK = true;
    }
    if (!a_rcvValue && (a_sendValueACK || a_sendValueNACK))
    {
        send_bStartGlueACK = false;
        send_bStartGlueNACK = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: look into how parameters are passed - by ref or by val. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: Maybe you should learn somthing about [`out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) and [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bool values you set are only [changed inside the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx) itself, not outside. Value types are copied to the method, not referenced. Setting it will change the copy, not the original.

A solution would be to use [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) to be able to pass in the values *and* change them:

```
public void LogPanelData( ref bool a_rcvValue
                        , ref bool a_sendValueACK
                        , ref bool a_sendValueNACK
                        , ref bool a_LogFile_OK
                        , string a_LogFileName
                        , string a_LogLines
                        )
{ }
```

Calling it needs `ref` then too:

```
LogPanelData( ref rcv_bStartGlue
            , ref send_bStartGlueACK
            , ref send_bStartGlueNACK
            , ref bLogRobotFile_OK
            , rcv_sFileNameRobot
            , LogLines
            );
```

A better approach would be be the use of a class to pass in. This might be helpful if the properties can always be grouped together.

```
public void LogPanelData( LogSettings logSettings
                        , string a_LogFileName
                        , string a_LogLines
                        )
{ }
```

This would require you to make a class `LogSettings`. Put in the properties there and pass this object along from one method to another. I am not sure but it might be good if the `string` arguments can be put in the class too.

Comment: If the OP wants to mutate those variables it would probably be better to wrap them in a class instead.

Comment: That would be an option too, depending on the situation. Thanks.

Comment: @juharr Well I'm creating log files and each of the file has a different name, file etc, maybe it is better to make a class for my logfiles. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @juharr Added a line about your approach.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding! You have just taken some really badly designed code and made it worse by adding `ref` everywhere. The proper answer is to completely rewrite the code with less reliance on multiple `bool` parameters and that returns the collective result, rather than being `void`.

Comment: @DavidArno I can agree on that. I don't see something that should be returned, but I have put in some more about the class. It seems the better option overall.